# An intelligent way to see if this surface is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, non-orientable-surfaces

I am trying to do this excercise:
\begin{array} { c } { \text { Let } M \text { be the regular surface in } \mathbb { R } ^ { 3 } \text { parametrised by } } \\ { X : \mathbb { R } \times ( - 1,1 ) \rightarrow \mathbb { R } ^ { 3 } \text { with } } \\ { X ( u , v ) = 2 ( \cos u , \sin u , 0 ) + v \sin ( u / 2 ) ( 0,0,1 ) } \\ { + v \cos ( u / 2 ) ( \cos u , \sin u , 0 ) } \\ { \text { The curve } \gamma : \mathbb { R } \rightarrow M \text { defined by } } \\  { \gamma : t \mapsto X ( t , 0 ) } \end{array}

Determine whether $\gamma$ is a geodesic and if $X(u,v)$ is orientable or not.

Using the geodesic equations I have seen when $\gamma$ is geodesic, but I am having troubles prooving the orientability. I want to know if there is an easy way to see that.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: This is a parametrization of the Möbius strip. Just out of curiosity, where did you get this exercise from?

Comment: Oh! I haven't realized that. Thanks!!. The book is "An introduction to Gaussian Geometry" of S. Gudmundsson. http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Gauss.pdf

Comment: Very nice, I recognized that exercise since the author of those notes is my very own teacher! It's always cool to see how many people use his notes! =)